# extract the remaining data from a dataset after filtering some data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

Suppose I am having dataframe like this:

```
Length    Width    Height
 100       150      130
 120       140      150 
 200       170      120
 250       190      180
 270       200      195
```

Now I want to filter the data from  three columns in a way like Length between (100-200) and width between (130-170) and Height between (120-150), if I extract the data like this, it will give me the data frame like

```
Length    Width   Height
 100       150      130
 120       140      150 
 200       170      120
```

and the remaining data from the dataframe is like

```
   Length    Width   Height
     250       190      180
     270       200      195
```

Now, I want to see both filtered data and the remaining data from the data set in a separate variables. How to get that in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use a boolean mask combining multiple `between` with `&`, and index difference:

```
mask = (df['Length'].between(100,200)
      & df['Width'].between(130,170)
      & df['Height'].between(120,150)
       )
df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df.loc[df.index.difference(df1.index)]
# or
# df2 = df[~mask]
```

output:

```
# df1
   Length  Width  Height
0     100    150     130
1     120    140     150
2     200    170     120

# df2
   Length  Width  Height
3     250    190     180
4     270    200     195
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work `df2 = df[~mask]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes it would